# user defined sql business rule in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have my business rule where I want to validate whether my field: afmeldingsdato is older than 3 months. If so then the data is incorrect and this leads to validation unsuccessful but I am struggling and cannot execute my rule in SSMS. Here is my sql script:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [usr].[olddates]
 (@MemberIdList  mdm.[MemberId] READONLY -- memberID is a user defined table data type.
            -- This parameter will pass along a list of members for which the action needs to run.
 ,@ModelName   NVARCHAR(MAX)
 ,@VersionName  NVARCHAR(MAX)
 ,@EntityName  NVARCHAR(MAX)
 ,@BusinessRuleName NVARCHAR(MAX)

)
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO [stg].[Emballageudbyder_master_statuskode_Leaf]
 (ImportType
 ,BatchTag
 ,Code
 ,ValidFrom)
SELECT
  0   -- import type 0 = inserting or updating members
 ,N'Business Rule Extension Test'
 ,Code  -- code of the member, supplied by @MemberIdList
 , where [Afmeldingsdato] > DATEADD(month, -3, getdate()) -- set ValidFrom to the current date
FROM @MemberIdList;

-- run the staging batch job to process the staging records
EXEC [stg].[Emballageudbyder_master_statuskode_Leaf]
   @VersionName = @VersionName
  ,@BatchTag  = N'Business Rule Extension Test';
END
```

But I am not able to execute this? can someone please help. 
ql

Comment: What error do you get? Is the `stg.Embalageudbyder_master_statuskode_Leaf` a SQL Agent job?

Comment: "not able to" means what exactly? An error? Unexpected behaviour? Something else? Please explain your problem clearly.

Comment: I get this error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure olddates, Line 25 [Batch Start Line 0]
Incorrect syntax near '>'.

Comment: No the stg.emballageudbyder.. is a staging table because I want my MDs business rule to work for this entity in MDS.

Answer (score 1):

So you are trying to just insert those records with a "valid" date...

The `WHERE` clause of a select statement syntactically has to be placed behind the `FROM` clause.

```
SELECT
  0   -- import type 0 = inserting or updating members
 ,N'Business Rule Extension Test'
 ,Code  -- code of the member, supplied by @MemberIdList
 , [Afmeldingsdato] -- set ValidFrom to the current date <<- ???
FROM @MemberIdList
where [Afmeldingsdato] > DATEADD(month, -3, getdate());
```

**Modified Version**

Assuming that you want to insert those records that violate the rule, your procedure should probably look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usr.olddates (
    @MemberIdList  mdm.MemberId READONLY -- list of members for which the action needs to run.
  , @ModelName   NVARCHAR(MAX)
  , @VersionName  NVARCHAR(MAX)
  , @EntityName  NVARCHAR(MAX)
  , @BusinessRuleName NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN

  -- insert the records with Afmeldingsdato older than 3 months
  INSERT INTO stg.Emballageudbyder_master_statuskode_Leaf(ImportType, BatchTag, Code, ValidFrom)
  SELECT 0, N'Business Rule Extension Test', [Code], [Afmeldingsdato]
  FROM @MemberIdList
  WHERE Afmeldingsdato < DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE());

  -- run the staging batch job to process the staging records
  EXEC stg.Emballageudbyder_master_statuskode_Leaf
    @VersionName = @VersionName
  , @BatchTag  = N'Business Rule Extension Test';

END
```

Comment: No I want it to tell me which part of my dataset violates this rule and not replace values.

Comment: I did not replace values but I replaced your `SELECT` statement by one that should not produce that syntax error. In which part of your code are you trying to implement `tell me`? Did you mean to insert only those records that **violate** the rule? If so, then your (and so mine) comparison operator `>` in the `WHERE` clause should point to the opposite direction (either `<` or `<=`). I don't want to sound mean, but I think that the best that you and your company can do is find a training course for basic T-SQL syntax before destroying things that others have built.

Comment: can you please send the script in the modified version in the way you think is correct, cause I am bit confused what you mean.

Comment: Just edited my answer and added the code that I think should work as expected.